# HTTP PUT call error to shopify when sending array in json request for metadata list type

Tags: json, api, http, go, shopify

This is an http PUT response to update the metafield of an existing article in shopify.

[PUT API documentation on Articles](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/article#put-blogs-blog-id-articles-article-id)

```
func UploadArticleListImg(client *http.Client, ArticleIDs []string, imageURL []string, blogID string) {

    newArticleQueryFinal := fmt.Sprintf(newArticleQuery, blogID)
  for _, ID := range ArticleIDs {

    Article := &ArticlePut{
        Blog_id: blogID,
        ID:      ID,
        Metafields: []ArticlePutMeta{
            {
                Key:       "flip_book_images",
                Value:     imageURL,
                Type:      "list.url",
                Namespace: "custom",
            },
        },
    }

    spew.Dump(Article)
    articleJSON, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"Article": Article})
    articleReq, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", newArticleQueryFinal, bytes.NewReader(articleJSON))
    articleReq.Header.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", token)
    articleReq.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(articleReq)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    sb := string(body)
    fmt.Println(sb)

    }

}
```

my structs are like below

```
type ArticlePut struct {
    Blog_id    string           `json:"blog_id"`
    ID         string           `json:"id"`
    Metafields []ArticlePutMeta `json:"metafields"`
}

type ArticlePutMeta struct {
    Key       string   `json:"key"`
    Value     []string `json:"value"`
    Type      string   `json:"type"`
    Namespace string   `json:"namespace"`
}
```

im getting an error saying

> 406 Not Acceptable

These are my Article metafield definitions.

[image]

and this is the documentation on the list_url metadata type

[image]

what am i missing here?? Please help.

Comment: What's the value of `newArticleQueryFinal`?

Comment: https://hit-parader.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-07/blogs/%s/articles.json and I add the blogID to %s

Comment: According to the [docs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/article#put-blogs-blog-id-articles-article-id) that *you* have linked the url's path must be `/admin/api/{version}/blogs/{blog_id}/articles/{article_id}.json`. Where in the code are you adding the article id to the url?

Comment: since im sending it in body im not specifying that. but maybe you are right. for PUT requests, you need to do that. because for POST i didnt. Let me try that

Comment: Ids are generated when the resource is created. POST is for creating, so at the time of a POST request you do not have an id to send, it would therefore make no sense for the API to ask it of you. PUT is different, it is used for updates of existing resources. Existing resources already have ids, and the PUT endpoint documentation clearly states that it's requried: https://imgur.com/a/UMaWTqZ

Comment: still error

400 Bad Request
{"errors":{"article":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250160/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-sp3llingzz).

Comment: If I input the values for metafield like below it works.
Value:     `["https://www.shopify.com","https://www.shopify.com","https://www.shopify.dev"]`

Answer (score 1):

If I input the values for metafield like below it works.

```
Value: `["https://www.shopify.com","https://www.shopify.com","https://www.shopify.dev"]`
```

But I dont know how to construct the imageURL to have single quotes around